# Creating monthly data from year data by keeping indicator variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

I have the following dataset:

```
householdnumber     begindate    enddate  typh   id.male    id.female
   001999            2000-01     2012-10    2        q1        q2
   001999            2012-10     2017-12    4        q1        q2
   101999            2005-01     2012-11    4        q3        q4
   101999            2012-11     2012-12    2        q3        q4
```

Each household consist of two persons (id male and id female) combined with a unique household number. Note that each household number is represented twice here as the type of household changes at a particular date (think of it as children are part of the household and after a particular date not anymore and vice versa).

My aim is to rewrite this data into monthly data using R. More precisely, the format I am looking for is this

```
 householdnumber      date      typh   id.male  id.female
    001999          2000-01      2        q1        q2
    001999          2000-02      2        q1        q2
     ....
    001999          2012-10      4        q1        q2
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I simply do not see how reshape or the pivot command is able to help me with this. Already thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Hi, can ypi post the output of `dput(head(your_data))` inside the question. Also please explain what `typh` should be like in the final output. Always equal to 2 except for the last row?

Answer (score 1):

one possibility using the `tidyverse` package would incorporate two steps:

- First, define a function which generates the desired dates for each row separately. For example such a function might look like this:

  ```
  my_fun <- function(ymon1, ymon2){

   dates <- as.Date(paste0(c(ymon1, ymon2), "-01"), format = "%Y-%m-%d")

   seq.Date(from = dates[1], to = dates[2], by = "month") %>%
     format("%Y-%m") %>%
     tibble(date = .)
  }
  ```

  To try this function, simply type something like `mfun("2000-01", "2001-05")`.
- Second, use `purrr::map2` to apply this function row-wise and unnest the result:

  ```
  library(tidyverse)

  mydata %>% 
    mutate(date = map2(begin_date, end_date, my_fun)) %>%
    unnest() %>%
    select(householdnumber, date, typh, id.male, id.female)

           householdnumber    date typh id.male id.female
       1            001999 2000-01    2      q1        q1
       2            001999 2000-02    2      q1        q1
       3            001999 2000-03    2      q1        q1
       4            001999 2000-04    2      q1        q1
       ...            ....                          ....
  ```

**Used data:**

```
mydata <- data.frame(householdnumber = c("001999","001999"),
           begin_date = c("2000-01", "2012-10"),
           end_date = c("2012-10", "2017-12"),
           typh = c(2L, 4L),
           id.male = c("q1", "q2"),
           id.female = c("q1", "q2"),
           stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: This does create a duplicate date entry whenever "typh" changes from 2 to 4.

Comment: I know but the OP hasn't specified which `typh` he wants.

Comment: True. However, I would assume that typh would switch to a new value as soon as it appears.